# Why is some of the text in Unity speckled pink?

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, fonts

[image]

This is very bizarre, and it wasn't always like this. I have no clue why only some of the text is pink like this, and I have no clue where to even start to fix it.

I have tried uninstalling both the editor and the hub, and checking all of my settings when reinstalling.
Anyone ever encountered this before?

Comment: nope never had pink text

Comment: same - did you fix this?

Comment: Nope, still pink